# testcafe freezing execution

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Experiencing a hard to diagnose the problem. When running all tests from .js file some of them are freezing without a timeout, same tests executed individually with -t "test name" are totally fine.
Same happening on local and cloud-based (Saucelabs) on multiple browsers.
What could cause something like that? 
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Any [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you could possibly share?

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp Tried to prepare minimal example code but unfortunately, the problem occurs when the whole suite is executed. When I make changes to scenario list freeze happens in a different place or not happening at all when suite is small.

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided is insufficient for me to determine the cause of the issue and find a precise solution.

I recommend that you try the latest testcafe version, [1.1.0 at the moment](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/releases), and see if this issue is reproducible.

If it is reproducible, please submit a bug report and provide as much detail as possible, so that the testcafe team can examine the issue and address it:

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to bring this to light again. We're using 1.15.2 and testcafe intermittently freezes during execution. We have not been able to find consistency on a test that is causing this and we can't get a report to spit out the error because it's freezing without finishing the status of the test run.

As originally stated, when we run a subset of tests, it seems to be fine, but running a 'full-suite', it freezes with no single root cause that we can see.

We're losing confidence in TestCafe from these issues and hope a solution is discovered soon.

Thanks,